# Как изменить положение кнопки?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap

Ребят, пишу на React "сайтик", использую bootsrap из webpack(npm). Проблема в том, что кнопка стоит почему-то ниже чем *textarea*, пример на фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код: (поверх этого когда, в другой компоненте еще сверху стоит класс container)

```
<div className='container-feedback'>
  <textarea value={text} onChange={e => onCommentChange(e.target.value) } />
  <button onClick={postComment} className='add'>Add</button>
</div>
```

```
textarea {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 0 20px;
 margin-top: 10px !important;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 line-height: 40px;
 border-width: 1;
 border-radius: 20px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.add {
   margin-left: 8px !important;
}
```

P.S: Если выровнять с помощью position: absolute + bottom, то при добавлении комментария, кнопка падает вниз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в стили:

```
.container-feedback{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз только сам понял! (чуть позже поставлю галочку)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй `.add{ vertical-align: top; margin:top:4px;}`